# Fatal error: Class ... not found in ... /ProviderRepository.php on line 146

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-5.1

This sounds like a trivial mistake, but I've been unable to find the solution for hours.

I tried to use https://github.com/michaelbonds/laravel-db2 in my Laravel project, and I added it using composer.

Here's my composer.json.

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
        "michaelb/laravel-db2": "~2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Here's the error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MichaelB\Database\DB2\DB2ServiceProvider' not found in /var/www/html/mysjsu/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 146
```

and

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]     
  Class 'MichaelB\Database\DB2\DB2ServiceProvider' not found
```

I found a similar question before on StackOverflow, and somebody suggested that the order matters. So, here's what I did in the following order:

1. add `"michaelb/laravel-db2": "~2.0"` to `composer.json`
2. run `php ../composer.phar update`
3. add `MichaelB\Database\DB2\DB2ServiceProvider::class` to the `providers` arary in `config/app.php`
4. run `php artisan migrate`

Any idea on what might've been the problem?

Comment: @andrewtweber I tried both redo everything, then use `composer install`, and do `composer update --no-scripts`, but it didn't fix it. It seems like the guy in that link hasn't installed the package yet, whereas I have. I actually can see the package's folder under `vendor` directory, and it has the class `DB2ServiceProvider` which is exactly the file that the compiler is complaining about. Any idea why? Thanks for the help, sorry if it sounds repetitive

Comment: try `composer dumpautoload` and `php artisan optimize`

Comment: @andrewtwebre I can do `composer dumpautoload`, but for `php artisan optimize` I'd have to comment out `MichaelB\Database\DB2\DB2ServiceProvider::class` from the providers array. If i didn't comment out that line, I'd get the same error. I'm still trying to understand what is the problem here, I can't see if there is anything wrong with the files

Comment: @andrewtweber it seems like the error only appears if I ran any of `php artisan` commands without removing `MichaelB\Database\DB2\DB2ServiceProvider::class` from the providers array

Comment: try commenting out the line in the providers array, then run those commands, then uncomment it?

Comment: @andrewtweber still doesn't work. I just tried to require the same package on my AWS instance, and apparently it gives the same error there. I wonder if the package is problematic because I can't use it both on my machine and on my cloud instance. Could you, by any chance, try to reproduce the error on your machine? I'm just wondering, from your experience, what usually caused this kind of problem?

Comment: @andrewtweber Oh man. I didn't know that.. Here's another package that seems to be compatible with L5 (https://github.com/opb/laravel-odbc-db2)[https://github.com/opb/laravel-odbc-db2]. Do you know how can I require it from my composer? I first tried `composer require opb/laravel-odbc-db2` but it says `"Could not find package opb/laravel-odbc-db2 at any version for your minimum-stability"`. Then I lowered my `minimum-stability` to `dev`, still no success. How can I add it manually to my `composer.json`? I don't know the version, so I tried ` "opb/laravel-odbc-db2" : "",`, but no success

Comment: actually I think his package will work in L5. Try my answer (just edited a second ago) and you should be good

Comment: Sorry I jumped the gun on saying this was a duplicate question, turns out it was the package's fault this time

Comment: @andrewtweber Wow thanks! This actually solves the problem! I wish I had enough reputation to vote you up 100 times :)

Comment: haha, you're welcome

Comment: See comments on the answer, Sven brings up a good point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This package is a fork of `cooperl/laravel-db2`. The documentation is inaccurate.

He changed the namespace to `MichaelB` but never tagged this as a stable version, so when you composer require his `~2.0`, packagist gives you an older version with the wrong namespace.

So when you run `composer update`, it runs some post-cmd scripts such as `php artisan optimize` which tries to pull from the config file but fails because that class doesn't exist.

Here's how to fix it:

1. Change composer.json to this version:

   ```
   "michaelb/laravel-db2": "dev-master"
   ```
2. Run `composer update --no-scripts`

Then you should be good.

Comment: Actually, depending on branches is a bad thing. Open an issue and ask the developer to tag a new release.

Comment: @Sven that's true. This guy disabled issues on his GitHub project though... what to do then? I would recommend that teamf use a different project or maybe the original source (`cooperl/laravel-db2`) instead of this fork, unless there is some reason he needs the fork

Comment: Exactly: If there is no working release, and no way to report issues, would you expect the software to work perfectly on the master branch? There are 77.000 packages registered, with 350.000 different versions. There should be a package with better developer support that solves the problem. Walk away from badly maintained packages.